# Parse csv with non-ASCII bytes into dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I am having trouble parsing a csv that contains non-ASCII bytes (bytes higher than 0x7F) into a dataframe.  First i tried below:

```
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", encoding='utf-8', engine='python')
```

I get an error: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 224: invalid start byte`.  I tried different encoding, but none of them seem to work.  Others will give a different error of some sort.

Then I tried reading it as a string that ignore errors and replace the bytes so that its clean.  Then push it into a dataframe:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import re

with open ("test.csv", "r", encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as myfile:
    data=myfile.read()

# get rid of the garbage in the input (raw bytes)
data = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9_\.;:\r\n,<>{}]', '', data)
data = data + '\n'   

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), index_col=None, header=0,
    skipinitialspace=True, sep='\r\n', parse_dates=True, engine='python')

print(df)
```

This excecutes but the dataframe will have 51 rows, where if you open `test.csv` it only has 46 rows, not including the titles.

Basically, how do I read the csv below and place it into a dataframe where it'll only have the 46 rows plus the title/heading.  I know the `sep` in the code above is not really working right in my code but is there a way to specify where each row starts? I believe the reason theres 51 rows is because there are \n (line feed) within the data, where \r\n (return and new line feed) is really what ends a row.

Copy the contents below and save as `test.csv` to test it out.

```
Source IP,Source Port,Destination IP,Destination Port,Protocol,Date(YYYY.MM.DD),Time(HH:MM:SS:ms),Data
127.0.0.1,49555,127.0.0.1,55946,IPPROTO_TCP,2019.01.29,14:26:03:165,
n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,ETH_P_ARP,2019.01.29,14:26:04:139,ÿÿÿÿÿÿà¯düà¯düÀ¨ÿÿÿÿÿÿÀ¨
n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,ETH_P_IPV6,2019.01.29,14:26:05:559,33à¯dü†Ý`:ÿþ€à¯ÿþdüÿ…!…à¯dü
n/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,ETH_P_IPV6,2019.01.29,14:26:09:567,33à¯dü†Ý`:ÿþ€à¯ÿþdüÿ…!…à¯dü
127.0.0.1,49100,127.0.0.1,59934,IPPROTO_TCP,2019.01.29,14:26:13:866,
127.0.0.1,49100,127.0.0.1,59934,IPPROTO_TCP,2019.01.29,14:26:13:870,"{
   ""EventName"" : ""ClearData"",
   ""Value"" : 0
}
"
127.0.0.1,59934,127.0.0.1,49100,IPPROTO_TCP,2019.01.29,14:26:13:870,
127.0.0.1,49015,127.0.0.1,64544,IPPROTO_TCP,2019.01.29,14:26:18:805,"{""DATA"":""DD"",""EVENT"":""CONTROL"",""ID"":""DD"",""MSG_TYPE"":""DATA""}"
127.0.0.1,64544,127.0.0.1,49015,IPPROTO_TCP,2019.01.29,14:26:18:805,
127.0.0.1,64542,127.0.0.1,49015,IPPROTO_TCP,2019.01.29,14:26:18:806,"{""EVENT"":""KEY_PRESSED"",""ID"":""DD"",""MSG_TYPE"":""RESUME""}"
127.0.0.1,49015,127.0.0.1,64542,IPPROTO_TCP,2019.01.29,14:26:18:806,"{""DATA"":""SET"",""EVENT"":""CONTROL"",""ID"":""DD"",""MSG_TYPE"":""ACK""}"
127.0.0.1,49015,127.0.0.1,64544,IPPROTO_TCP,2019.01.29,14:26:18:827,"{""DATA"":""H010122D887"",""EVENT"":""SDU_DATA"",""ID"":""DD"",""MSG_TYPE"":""DATA""}"
127.0.0.1,n/a,127.0.0.1,n/a,IPPROTO_ICMP,2019.01.29,14:26:23:556,«ÞEA@@#§îÂ5-þ@¹0rhelpoolntporg
127.0.0.1,n/a,127.0.0.1,n/a,IPPROTO_ICMP,2019.01.29,14:26:23:556,¶EA@@#¦îÂ5-þ@7C0rhelpoolntporg
127.0.0.1,n/a,127.0.0.1,n/a,IPPROTO_ICMP,2019.01.29,14:26:23:556,§»EA@@#¥òå5-þ@¹0rhelpoolntporg
127.0.0.1,n/a,127.0.0.1,n/a,IPPROTO_ICMP,2019.01.29,14:26:23:556,“EA@@#¤òå5-þ@7C0rhelpoolntporg
127.0.0.1,n/a,127.0.0.1,n/a,IPPROTO_ICMP,2019.01.29,14:26:23:556,":iEK@@#™òY57þJpÅ0rhelpoolntporg   localhost"
127.0.0.1,n/a,127.0.0.1,n/a,IPPROTO_ICMP,2019.01.29,14:26:23:557,"³VEK@@#˜òY57þJÜ×0rhelpoolntporg   localhost"
127.0.0.1,n/a,127.0.0.1,n/a,IPPROTO_ICMP,2019.01.29,14:26:23:557,"FÃEK  @@#—åÿ57þJpÅ0rhelpoolntporg localhost"
127.0.0.1,n/a,127.0.0.1,n/a,IPPROTO_ICMP,2019.01.29,14:26:23:557,"¿°EK
@@#–åÿ57þJÜ×0rhelpoolntporg localhost"
127.0.0.1,n/a,127.0.0.1,n/a,IPPROTO_ICMP,2019.01.29,14:26:23:557,>³EA@@#ŸÜû5-þ@81rhelpoolntporg
127.0.0.1,n/a,127.0.0.1,n/a,IPPROTO_ICMP,2019.01.29,14:26:23:557,K£EA@@#žÜû5-þ@1rhelpoolntporg
127.0.0.1,n/a,127.0.0.1,n/a,IPPROTO_ICMP,2019.01.29,14:26:23:557,"JŽEA
@@#Ñ 5-þ@81rhelpoolntporg"
127.0.0.1,n/a,127.0.0.1,n/a,IPPROTO_ICMP,2019.01.29,14:26:23:557,W~EA@@#œÑ 5-þ@1rhelpoolntporg
127.0.0.1,n/a,127.0.0.1,n/a,IPPROTO_ICMP,2019.01.29,14:26:23:558,"®¶EK@@#‘Ê£57þJ$-1rhelpoolntporg   localhost"
127.0.0.1,n/a,127.0.0.1,n/a,IPPROTO_ICMP,2019.01.29,14:26:23:558,"W¢EK@@#Ê£57þJ`A1rhelpoolntporg    localhost"
127.0.0.1,n/a,127.0.0.1,n/a,IPPROTO_ICMP,2019.01.29,14:26:23:558,"•ùEK@@#ã`57þJ$-1rhelpoolntporg    localhost"
127.0.0.1,n/a,127.0.0.1,n/a,IPPROTO_ICMP,2019.01.29,14:26:23:558,">åEK@@#Žã`57þJ`A1rhelpoolntporg   localhost"
127.0.0.1,n/a,127.0.0.1,n/a,IPPROTO_ICMP,2019.01.29,14:26:23:558,R]EA@@#—Í5-þ@4B2rhelpoolntporg
127.0.0.1,n/a,127.0.0.1,n/a,IPPROTO_ICMP,2019.01.29,14:26:23:558,ãNEA@@#–Í5-þ@ˆP2rhelpoolntporg
127.0.0.1,n/a,127.0.0.1,n/a,IPPROTO_ICMP,2019.01.29,14:26:23:558,SxEA@@#•Ëÿ5-þ@4B2rhelpoolntporg
127.0.0.1,n/a,127.0.0.1,n/a,IPPROTO_ICMP,2019.01.29,14:26:23:558,äiEA@@#”Ëÿ5-þ@ˆP2rhelpoolntporg
127.0.0.1,n/a,127.0.0.1,n/a,IPPROTO_ICMP,2019.01.29,14:26:23:559,"ÃFEK@@#‰ùY57þJàå2rhelpoolntporg   localhost"
127.0.0.1,n/a,127.0.0.1,n/a,IPPROTO_ICMP,2019.01.29,14:26:23:559,"T6EK@@#ˆùY57þJ4ö2rhelpoolntporg   localhost"
127.0.0.1,n/a,127.0.0.1,n/a,IPPROTO_ICMP,2019.01.29,14:26:23:559,"÷‚EK@@#‡Å57þJàå2rhelpoolntporg    localhost"
127.0.0.1,n/a,127.0.0.1,n/a,IPPROTO_ICMP,2019.01.29,14:26:23:559,"ˆrEK@@#†Å57þJ4ö2rhelpoolntporg    localhost"
127.0.0.1,n/a,127.0.0.1,n/a,IPPROTO_ICMP,2019.01.29,14:26:23:559,YEA@@#íÙ5-þ@Q†3rhelpoolntporg
127.0.0.1,n/a,127.0.0.1,n/a,IPPROTO_ICMP,2019.01.29,14:26:23:559,ÝEA@@#ŽíÙ5-þ@83rhelpoolntporg
127.0.0.1,n/a,127.0.0.1,n/a,IPPROTO_ICMP,2019.01.29,14:26:23:559,0+EA@@#Ò5-þ@Q†3rhelpoolntporg
127.0.0.1,n/a,127.0.0.1,n/a,IPPROTO_ICMP,2019.01.29,14:26:23:560,.¯EA@@#ŒÒ5-þ@83rhelpoolntporg
127.0.0.1,n/a,127.0.0.1,n/a,IPPROTO_ICMP,2019.01.29,14:26:23:560,"\½EK@@#Ô57þJl*3rhelpoolntporg localhost"
127.0.0.1,n/a,127.0.0.1,n/a,IPPROTO_ICMP,2019.01.29,14:26:23:560,"«EK @@#€Ô57þJ<3rhelpoolntporg localhost"
127.0.0.1,n/a,127.0.0.1,n/a,IPPROTO_ICMP,2019.01.29,14:26:23:560,"?fEK!@@#ñô57þJl*3rhelpoolntporg   localhost"
127.0.0.1,n/a,127.0.0.1,n/a,IPPROTO_ICMP,2019.01.29,14:26:23:560,"TEK""@@#~ñô57þJ<3rhelpoolntporg   localhost"
127.0.0.1,49020,127.0.0.1,62568,IPPROTO_TCP,2019.01.29,14:26:23:701,"{""heartbeat"" : {""sequence"": 8 }}
"
127.0.0.1,6700,127.0.0.1,53332,IPPR,,,
```

print(open("test.csv", "rb").read()):

```
b'Source IP,Source Port,Destination IP,Destination Port,Protocol,Date(YYYY.MM.DD),Time(HH:MM:SS:ms),Data\r\n127.0.0.1,49555,127.0.0.1,55946,IPPROTO_TCP,2019.01.29,14:26:03:165,\r\nn/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,ETH_P_ARP,2019.01.29,14:26:04:139,\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xe0\xafd\xfc\x8f\x08\x06\x01\x08\x06\x04\x01\xe0\xafd\xfc\x8f\xc0\xa8\x01\x07\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xc0\xa8\x01\x07\r\nn/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,ETH_P_IPV6,2019.01.29,14:26:05:559,33\x02\xe0\xafd\xfc\x8f\x86\xdd`\x10:\xff\xfe\x80\x02\xe0\xaf\xff\xfed\xfc\x8f\xff\x02\x02\x85!\x85\x01\x01\xe0\xafd\xfc\x8f\r\nn/a,n/a,n/a,n/a,ETH_P_IPV6,2019.01.29,14:26:09:567,33\x02\xe0\xafd\xfc\x8f\x86\xdd`\x10:\xff\xfe\x80\x02\xe0\xaf\xff\xfed\xfc\x8f\xff\x02\x02\x85!\x85\x01\x01\xe0\xafd\xfc\x8f\r\n127.0.0.1,49100,127.0.0.1,59934,IPPROTO_TCP,2019.01.29,14:26:13:866,\r\n127.0.0.1,49100,127.0.0.1,59934,IPPROTO_TCP,2019.01.29,14:26:13:870,"{\n   ""EventName"" : ""ClearData"",\n   ""Value"" : 0\n}\n"\r\n127.0.0.1,59934,127.0.0.1,49100,IPPROTO_TCP,2019.01.29,14:26:13:870,\r\n127.0.0.1,49015,127.0.0.1,64544,IPPROTO_TCP,2019.01.29,14:26:18:805,"{""DATA"":""DD"",""EVENT"":""CONTROL"",""ID"":""DD"",""MSG_TYPE"":""DATA""}"\r\n127.0.0.1,64544,127.0.0.1,49015,IPPROTO_TCP,2019.01.29,14:26:18:805,\r\n127.0.0.1,64542,127.0.0.1,49015,IPPROTO_TCP,2019.01.29,14:26:18:806,"{""EVENT"":""KEY_PRESSED"",""ID"":""DD"",""MSG_TYPE"":""RESUME""}"\r\n127.0.0.1,49015,127.0.0.1,64542,IPPROTO_TCP,2019.01.29,14:26:18:806,"{""DATA"":""SET"",""EVENT"":""CONTROL"",""ID"":""DD"",""MSG_TYPE"":""ACK""}"\r\n127.0.0.1,49015,127.0.0.1,64544,IPPROTO_TCP,2019.01.29,14:26:18:827,"{""DATA"":""H010122D887"",""EVENT"":""SDU_DATA"",""ID"":""DD"",""MSG_TYPE"":""DATA""}"\r\n127.0.0.1,n/a,127.0.0.1,n/a,IPPROTO_ICMP,2019.01.29,14:26:23:556,\x03\x03\xab\xdeEA\x19\x03@@\x11#\xa7\x7f\x01\x7f\x01\xee\xc25-\xfe@\xb9\x1a\x01\x01\x010\x04rhel\x04pool\x03ntp\x03org\x01\x01\r\n127.0.0.1,n/a,127.0.0.1,n/a,IPPROTO_ICMP,2019.01.29,14:26:23:556,\x03\x03\x12\xb6EA\x19\x04@@\x11#\xa6\x7f\x01\x7f\x01\xee\xc25-\xfe@7C\x01\x01\x010\x04rhel\x04pool\x03ntp\x03org\x1c\x01\r\n127.0.0.1,n/a,127.0.0.1,n/a,IPPROTO_ICMP,2019.01.29,14:26:23:556,\x03\x03\xa7\xbbEA\x19\x05@@\x11#\xa5\x7f\x01\x7f\x01\xf2\xe55-\xfe@\xb9\x1a\x01\x01\x010\x04rhel\x04pool\x03ntp\x03org\x01\x01\r\n127.0.0.1,n/a,127.0.0.1,n/a,IPPROTO_ICMP,2019.01.29,14:26:23:556,\x03\x03\x0e\x93EA\x19\x06@@\x11#\xa4\x7f\x01\x7f\x01\xf2\xe55-\xfe@7C\x01\x01\x010\x04rhel\x04pool\x03ntp\x03org\x1c\x01\r\n127.0.0.1,n/a,127.0.0.1,n/a,IPPROTO_ICMP,2019.01.29,14:26:23:556,"\x03\x03:iEK\x19\x07@@\x11#\x99\x7f\x01\x7f\x01\xf2Y57\xfeJp\xc5\x01\x01\x010\x04rhel\x04pool\x03ntp\x03org\tlocalhost\x01\x01"\r\n127.0.0.1,n/a,127.0.0.1,n/a,IPPROTO_ICMP,2019.01.29,14:26:23:557,"\x03\x03\xb3VEK\x19\x08@@\x11#\x98\x7f\x01\x7f\x01\xf2Y57\xfeJ\xdc\xd7\x01\x01\x010\x04rhel\x04pool\x03ntp\x03org\tlocalhost\x1c\x01"\r\n127.0.0.1,n/a,127.0.0.1,n/a,IPPROTO_ICMP,2019.01.29,14:26:23:557,"\x03\x03F\xc3EK\x19\t@@\x11#\x97\x7f\x01\x7f\x01\xe5\xff57\xfeJp\xc5\x01\x01\x010\x04rhel\x04pool\x03ntp\x03org\tlocalhost\x01\x01"\r\n127.0.0.1,n/a,127.0.0.1,n/a,IPPROTO_ICMP,2019.01.29,14:26:23:557,"\x03\x03\xbf\xb0EK\x19\n@@\x11#\x96\x7f\x01\x7f\x01\xe5\xff57\xfeJ\xdc\xd7\x01\x01\x010\x04rhel\x04pool\x03ntp\x03org\tlocalhost\x1c\x01"\r\n127.0.0.1,n/a,127.0.0.1,n/a,IPPROTO_ICMP,2019.01.29,14:26:23:557,\x03\x03>\xb3EA\x19\x0b@@\x11#\x9f\x7f\x01\x7f\x01\xdc\xfb5-\xfe@8\x0c\x01\x01\x011\x04rhel\x04pool\x03ntp\x03org\x01\x01\r\n127.0.0.1,n/a,127.0.0.1,n/a,IPPROTO_ICMP,2019.01.29,14:26:23:557,\x03\x03K\xa3EA\x19\x0c@@\x11#\x9e\x7f\x01\x7f\x01\xdc\xfb5-\xfe@\x10\x1c\x01\x01\x011\x04rhel\x04pool\x03ntp\x03org\x1c\x01\r\n127.0.0.1,n/a,127.0.0.1,n/a,IPPROTO_ICMP,2019.01.29,14:26:23:557,"\x03\x03J\x8eEA\x19\r@@\x11#\x9d\x7f\x01\x7f\x01\xd1 5-\xfe@8\x0c\x01\x01\x011\x04rhel\x04pool\x03ntp\x03org\x01\x01"\r\n127.0.0.1,n/a,127.0.0.1,n/a,IPPROTO_ICMP,2019.01.29,14:26:23:557,\x03\x03W~EA\x19\x0e@@\x11#\x9c\x7f\x01\x7f\x01\xd1 5-\xfe@\x10\x1c\x01\x01\x011\x04rhel\x04pool\x03ntp\x03org\x1c\x01\r\n127.0.0.1,n/a,127.0.0.1,n/a,IPPROTO_ICMP,2019.01.29,14:26:23:558,"\x03\x03\xae\xb6EK\x19\x0f@@\x11#\x91\x7f\x01\x7f\x01\xca\xa357\xfeJ$-\x01\x01\x011\x04rhel\x04pool\x03ntp\x03org\tlocalhost\x01\x01"\r\n127.0.0.1,n/a,127.0.0.1,n/a,IPPROTO_ICMP,2019.01.29,14:26:23:558,"\x03\x03W\xa2EK\x19\x10@@\x11#\x90\x7f\x01\x7f\x01\xca\xa357\xfeJ`A\x01\x01\x011\x04rhel\x04pool\x03ntp\x03org\tlocalhost\x1c\x01"\r\n127.0.0.1,n/a,127.0.0.1,n/a,IPPROTO_ICMP,2019.01.29,14:26:23:558,"\x03\x03\x95\xf9EK\x19\x11@@\x11#\x8f\x7f\x01\x7f\x01\xe3`57\xfeJ$-\x01\x01\x011\x04rhel\x04pool\x03ntp\x03org\tlocalhost\x01\x01"\r\n127.0.0.1,n/a,127.0.0.1,n/a,IPPROTO_ICMP,2019.01.29,14:26:23:558,"\x03\x03>\xe5EK\x19\x12@@\x11#\x8e\x7f\x01\x7f\x01\xe3`57\xfeJ`A\x01\x01\x011\x04rhel\x04pool\x03ntp\x03org\tlocalhost\x1c\x01"\r\n127.0.0.1,n/a,127.0.0.1,n/a,IPPROTO_ICMP,2019.01.29,14:26:23:558,\x03\x03R]EA\x19\x13@@\x11#\x97\x7f\x01\x7f\x01\xcd\x1a5-\xfe@4B\x01\x01\x012\x04rhel\x04pool\x03ntp\x03org\x01\x01\r\n127.0.0.1,n/a,127.0.0.1,n/a,IPPROTO_ICMP,2019.01.29,14:26:23:558,\x03\x03\xe3NEA\x19\x14@@\x11#\x96\x7f\x01\x7f\x01\xcd\x1a5-\xfe@\x88P\x01\x01\x012\x04rhel\x04pool\x03ntp\x03org\x1c\x01\r\n127.0.0.1,n/a,127.0.0.1,n/a,IPPROTO_ICMP,2019.01.29,14:26:23:558,\x03\x03SxEA\x19\x15@@\x11#\x95\x7f\x01\x7f\x01\xcb\xff5-\xfe@4B\x01\x01\x012\x04rhel\x04pool\x03ntp\x03org\x01\x01\r\n127.0.0.1,n/a,127.0.0.1,n/a,IPPROTO_ICMP,2019.01.29,14:26:23:558,\x03\x03\xe4iEA\x19\x16@@\x11#\x94\x7f\x01\x7f\x01\xcb\xff5-\xfe@\x88P\x01\x01\x012\x04rhel\x04pool\x03ntp\x03org\x1c\x01\r\n127.0.0.1,n/a,127.0.0.1,n/a,IPPROTO_ICMP,2019.01.29,14:26:23:559,"\x03\x03\xc3FEK\x19\x17@@\x11#\x89\x7f\x01\x7f\x01\xf9Y57\xfeJ\xe0\xe5\x01\x01\x012\x04rhel\x04pool\x03ntp\x03org\tlocalhost\x01\x01"\r\n127.0.0.1,n/a,127.0.0.1,n/a,IPPROTO_ICMP,2019.01.29,14:26:23:559,"\x03\x03T6EK\x19\x18@@\x11#\x88\x7f\x01\x7f\x01\xf9Y57\xfeJ4\xf6\x01\x01\x012\x04rhel\x04pool\x03ntp\x03org\tlocalhost\x1c\x01"\r\n127.0.0.1,n/a,127.0.0.1,n/a,IPPROTO_ICMP,2019.01.29,14:26:23:559,"\x03\x03\xf7\x82EK\x19\x19@@\x11#\x87\x7f\x01\x7f\x01\xc5\x1d57\xfeJ\xe0\xe5\x01\x01\x012\x04rhel\x04pool\x03ntp\x03org\tlocalhost\x01\x01"\r\n127.0.0.1,n/a,127.0.0.1,n/a,IPPROTO_ICMP,2019.01.29,14:26:23:559,"\x03\x03\x88rEK\x19\x1a@@\x11#\x86\x7f\x01\x7f\x01\xc5\x1d57\xfeJ4\xf6\x01\x01\x012\x04rhel\x04pool\x03ntp\x03org\tlocalhost\x1c\x01"\r\n127.0.0.1,n/a,127.0.0.1,n/a,IPPROTO_ICMP,2019.01.29,14:26:23:559,\x03\x03\x14YEA\x19\x1b@@\x11#\x8f\x7f\x01\x7f\x01\xed\xd95-\xfe@Q\x86\x01\x01\x013\x04rhel\x04pool\x03ntp\x03org\x01\x01\r\n127.0.0.1,n/a,127.0.0.1,n/a,IPPROTO_ICMP,2019.01.29,14:26:23:559,\x03\x03\x12\xddEA\x19\x1c@@\x11#\x8e\x7f\x01\x7f\x01\xed\xd95-\xfe@8\x02\x01\x01\x013\x04rhel\x04pool\x03ntp\x03org\x1c\x01\r\n127.0.0.1,n/a,127.0.0.1,n/a,IPPROTO_ICMP,2019.01.29,14:26:23:559,\x03\x030+EA\x19\x1d@@\x11#\x8d\x7f\x01\x7f\x01\xd2\x075-\xfe@Q\x86\x01\x01\x013\x04rhel\x04pool\x03ntp\x03org\x01\x01\r\n127.0.0.1,n/a,127.0.0.1,n/a,IPPROTO_ICMP,2019.01.29,14:26:23:560,\x03\x03.\xafEA\x19\x1e@@\x11#\x8c\x7f\x01\x7f\x01\xd2\x075-\xfe@8\x02\x01\x01\x013\x04rhel\x04pool\x03ntp\x03org\x1c\x01\r\n127.0.0.1,n/a,127.0.0.1,n/a,IPPROTO_ICMP,2019.01.29,14:26:23:560,"\x03\x03\\\xbdEK\x19\x1f@@\x11#\x81\x7f\x01\x7f\x01\xd4\x9d57\xfeJl*\x01\x01\x013\x04rhel\x04pool\x03ntp\x03org\tlocalhost\x01\x01"\r\n127.0.0.1,n/a,127.0.0.1,n/a,IPPROTO_ICMP,2019.01.29,14:26:23:560,"\x03\x03\x1d\xabEK\x19 @@\x11#\x80\x7f\x01\x7f\x01\xd4\x9d57\xfeJ\x90<\x01\x01\x013\x04rhel\x04pool\x03ntp\x03org\tlocalhost\x1c\x01"\r\n127.0.0.1,n/a,127.0.0.1,n/a,IPPROTO_ICMP,2019.01.29,14:26:23:560,"\x03\x03?fEK\x19!@@\x11#\x7f\x7f\x01\x7f\x01\xf1\xf457\xfeJl*\x01\x01\x013\x04rhel\x04pool\x03ntp\x03org\tlocalhost\x01\x01"\r\n127.0.0.1,n/a,127.0.0.1,n/a,IPPROTO_ICMP,2019.01.29,14:26:23:560,"\x03\x03TEK\x19""@@\x11#~\x7f\x01\x7f\x01\xf1\xf457\xfeJ\x90<\x01\x01\x013\x04rhel\x04pool\x03ntp\x03org\tlocalhost\x1c\x01"\r\n127.0.0.1,49020,127.0.0.1,62568,IPPROTO_TCP,2019.01.29,14:26:23:701,"{""heartbeat"" : {""sequence"": 8 }}\n"\r\n127.0.0.1,6700,127.0.0.1,53332,IPPR,,,\r\n'
```

Comment: " a csv that contains raw bytes" What does that mean? All files, fundamentally, are just bytes. Why are you adding `sep='\r\n'` as a seperator? The separator here is clearly a comma, i.e. just the default `sep=','` should work...?

Comment: changing it to ',' doesnt do anything.  Still generate the same 9 rows.  You can try it yourself.

Comment: I did. But don't read the file in first. I jsut copy-pasted it into a file and read the file directly with `pd.read_csv`. I get a 7 x 8 data-frame.

Comment: Look, just add what `print(open ("test.csv", "rb").read())` gives you to the question. Then we'll know exactly what is in the file.

Comment: Oh ok, sorry with the small portion of the csv, it actually works fine if i use encoding utf-8.  But please try the updated test.csv above and just reading it with pd.read_csv should give you 51 x 8 data-frame, where it should only be 46 rows.  Please let me know if you see the same issue as me

Comment: I get `df.shape == (46, 8)` if I use `pd.read_csv` with just the default arguments. Again, **provide the output of `print(open ("test.csv", "rb").read())` so we know exactly what is in your file**.

Comment: Thats weird yours works ok.  But I updated above to show what the binary output is on mine

Comment: If I do `pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data.decode('utf8',errors='ignore')))` I get a 46X8 data-frame. I tried chardetect and it didn't resolve the encoding.

Comment: The problem seems to be you have simply some "data" column which isn't text, but you are using a text-based representation (i.e. csv) to serialize it. You should choose something else.